# c++11 - getting result_of, decltype, std::function and variadic templates working together

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, decltype, std-function

I'm having quite the trouble with using std::result_of, decltype and std::function

with variadic templates .

I have the following function function -

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c) {
    std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the following class

```
template <class T, class... Args>
class VariadicTest {
public:
    VariadicTest(const T& func, Args... args) : func(func) {};
private:
    T func;
};
```

I would like to have a member in the class to save a lambda expression,

for this I need an std::function .

My question is how would I define that std::function properly .

A usecase of this class will look like -

```
VariadicTest(foo, 1,2,3);
```

So now I have T = int __cdecl (int, int, int) and Args = (int - 1, int - 2, int - 3)

From this I would like a member function that would look as such:

```
std::function<std::result_of<T(Args...)::type(Args...)>
```

now this of course does not compile, nor did 50 or so other stuff I tried .

Basically I need for this example the following declaration

```
std::function<int(int,int,int)> _f;
```

And of course for this to be automated per T and Args given .

Comment: Did you try `std::function<typename std::result_of<T(Args...)::type(Args...)>`   or a separate typedef to obtain the result type?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements of the class. What is it trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
class VariadicTest {
public:
    VariadicTest(const T& func, Args... args) : func(std::bind(func, args...)) {};
private:
    using result_type_t = typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type;
    std::function<result_type_t()> func;
};
```

Comment: @dyp Was it? It compiled on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cedc85e569fead57). Okay, I'll change it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes: you want to initialize a *function wrapper* (the member `func`) with something that's callable. The arguments itself are not callable. Note that binding the arguments to the function object will produce something that's callable *without any further arguments*. Therefore the function type has to be `result_type()`, unless you want to pass further arguments.

Comment: The part `decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Args>()...))` might be replaceable with `typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type`. When you introduce `template<class T> using result_of_t = typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type;`, it might become more readable: `using result_type = result_of_t<T(Args...)>;`